# Live/Hotmail REST Api to get full email, phone and fax numbers

Tags: c#, hotmail

As some guidelines on net, this is the way I used to get live/hotmail contacts information:

call this url to get Access token:
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=MyClientID&response_type=token&scope=MyScope&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf

Then call this to get all contacts:
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?parameters-like-access-token-here

MyScope: **wl.basic%20wl.contacts_emails%20wl.contacts_phone_numbers**

This returns me all contacts name, emails, phones but lack of home fax and work fax, seems like **wl.contacts_phone_numbers** doesn't include fax numbers !

Can anyone help me what is the scope for getting full emails, phone and fax numbers ?

Comment: Yeah, the docs say you get all the user information from the /me call, but I only get 8 really basic fields, not including any of the email stuff.